# Another tricky way to delay?

Tags: android

I need to apply animation for my layout, the animation's duration is 200 milisec as below

```
<scale
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:toXScale="0.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="0.0"
    android:duration="200"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%" />
```

this is closing animation, so right after it finish, i must remove the view using this:

```
mWindowManager.removeView(myView);
```

but problem is, it wont wait 200 milisec for the animation to finish, it removeView immediately so user think there is no closing animation (I know because I tried not removeView after animation, it work but the view still there)
I tried to use handler as below to delay the removeView:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(()->{
            mWindowManager.removeView(myView);
        }, 200);
```

but error showed up:

```
IllegalArgumentException: View=com.example.administrator.AssistiveTouch.MyGroupView{683f971 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0} not attached to window manager
```

I think the cause is the handler works in a diffirent instance (or thread, or something, sorry am kind of bad at English) so it cant find myView

is there any diffirent way to delay the app to give the animation some time to execute?

Comment: use the animation listener and from that write your remove code in animation complete method

Comment: @VivekMishra can you explain further pls, or an example code, am quite new

Comment: search for animation listeners and you will understand

Comment: @VivekMishra ah yess, it work !!! how simple, thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than try to 'time' the end of an animation, you should really just react to it based on a callback.

The problem with trying to 'time' the end of an animation is that there's no guarantee for consistency. What if your removing View code starts while the View is still animating? There's no more View to animate, which means a crash is inevitable.

What Animation class are you using for your closing animation? There should be a callback interface for you to respond to when an animation ends.

For example, if you're using an `ObjectAnimator` there's an `animator.addListener(Animator.AnimationListener listener)` method with a `onAnimationEnd()` callback.

Simply place your `removeView()` code inside that `onAnimationEnd()` callback and it'll run as soon as the animation ends.

So look into the Animator class you're using and check for an animation listener.

Comment: yes, I didnt know about animation listener before. It work now, thank you!